# I have a php validator and it returns true, but I need to add the false

Tags: php, validation

I need help with this code, is a credit card validation, I been trying to make it work in my code but I can't, I just need to obtain 2 variables, is the card is working it should return true that works, but if not it shows an error message, but I also need to obtain a return false, here is the code:

```
    <?php
    $cardnumber = $_POST['CardNumber']; 
    $cardname = $_POST['CardType'];

    $cards = array (  array ('name' => 'American Express', 
    'length' => '15', 
    'prefixes' => '34,37',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'Diners Club Carte Blanche', 
    'length' => '14', 
    'prefixes' => '300,301,302,303,304,305',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'Diners Club', 
    'length' => '14,16',
    'prefixes' => '36,38,54,55',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'Discover', 
    'length' => '16', 
    'prefixes' => '6011,622,64,65',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'Diners Club Enroute', 
    'length' => '15', 
    'prefixes' => '2014,2149',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'JCB', 
    'length' => '16', 
    'prefixes' => '35',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'Maestro', 
    'length' => '12,13,14,15,16,18,19', 
    'prefixes' => '5018,5020,5038,6304,6759,6761,6762,6763',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
                       array ('name' => 'MasterCard', 
    'length' => '16', 
    'prefixes' => '51,52,53,54,55',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'Solo', 
    'length' => '16,18,19', 
    'prefixes' => '6334,6767',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
                       array ('name' => 'Switch', 
    'length' => '16,18,19', 
    'prefixes' => '4903,4905,4911,4936,564182,633110,6333,6759',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'VISA', 
    'length' => '16', 
    'prefixes' => '4',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'VISA Electron', 
    'length' => '16', 
    'prefixes' => '417500,4917,4913,4508,4844',
    'checkdigit' => true
    ),
    array ('name' => 'LaserCard', 
    'length' => '16,17,18,19', 
    'prefixes' => '6304,6706,6771,6709',
    'checkdigit' => true
    )
    );

      $ccErrorNo = 0;

      $ccErrors [0] = "Unknown card type";
      $ccErrors [1] = "No card number provided";
      $ccErrors [2] = "Credit card number has invalid format";
      $ccErrors [3] = "Credit card number is invalid";
      $ccErrors [4] = "Credit card number is wrong length";

      // Establish card type
      $cardType = -1;
      for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($cards); $i++) {

        // See if it is this card (ignoring the case of the string)
        if (strtolower($cardname) == strtolower($cards[$i]['name'])) {
          $cardType = $i;
          break;
        }
      }

      // If card type not found, report an error
      if ($cardType == -1) {
         $errornumber = 0;     
         $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
         return true; 
      }

      // Ensure that the user has provided a credit card number
      if (strlen($cardnumber) == 0)  {
         $errornumber = 1;     
         $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
         return true; 
      }

      // Remove any spaces from the credit card number
      $cardNo = str_replace (' ', '', $cardnumber);  

      // Check that the number is numeric and of the right sort of length.
      if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{13,19}$/",$cardNo))  {
         $errornumber = 2;     
         $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
         return true; 
      }

      // Now check the modulus 10 check digit - if required
      if ($cards[$cardType]['checkdigit']) {
        $checksum = 0;        // running checksum total
        $mychar = "";         // next char to process
        $j = 1;               // takes value of 1 or 2

        // Process each digit one by one starting at the right
        for ($i = strlen($cardNo) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {

          // Extract the next digit and multiply by 1 or 2 on alternative digits.      
          $calc = $cardNo{$i} * $j;

          // If the result is in two digits add 1 to the checksum total
          if ($calc > 9) {
            $checksum = $checksum + 1;
            $calc = $calc - 10;
          }

          // Add the units element to the checksum total
          $checksum = $checksum + $calc;

          // Switch the value of j
          if ($j ==1) {$j = 2;} else {$j = 1;};
        } 

        // All done - if checksum is divisible by 10, it is a valid modulus 10.
        // If not, report an error.
        if ($checksum % 10 != 0) {
         $errornumber = 3;     
         $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
         return true; 
        }
      }  

      // The following are the card-specific checks we undertake.

      // Load an array with the valid prefixes for this card
      $prefix = explode(',',$cards[$cardType]['prefixes']);

      // Now see if any of them match what we have in the card number  
      $PrefixValid = false; 
      for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($prefix); $i++) {
        $exp = '/^' . $prefix[$i] . '/';
        if (preg_match($exp,$cardNo)) {
          $PrefixValid = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      // If it isn't a valid prefix there's no point at looking at the length
      if (!$PrefixValid) {
         $errornumber = 3;     
         $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
         return true; 
      }

      // See if the length is valid for this card
      $LengthValid = false;
      $lengths = explode(',',$cards[$cardType]['length']);
      for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($lengths); $j++) {
        if (strlen($cardNo) == $lengths[$j]) {
          $LengthValid = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      // See if all is OK by seeing if the length was valid. 
      if (!$LengthValid) {
         $errornumber = 4;     
         $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
         return true; 
      };   

      // The credit card is in the required format.
      return true;

echo $errortext;
?>
```

you can see there is return true, but I also need to change this to false when the card is not validated so I can make other validation, thanks for any help.

I find other code that do what I need, is a little more simple, is possible to add the $verified variable of this new code to the first one? here is the code:

```
<?php

$cc_number = $_POST['CardNumber']; 
$type = $_POST['CardType'];

$cc_num = str_replace (' ', '', $cc_number);  

    if($type == "AX") {
    $denum = "American Express";
    } elseif($type == "DC") {
    $denum = "Diner's Club";
    } elseif($type == "DS") {
    $denum = "Discover";
    } elseif($type == "MC") {
    $denum = "Master Card";
    } elseif($type == "VI") {
    $denum = "Visa";
    }

    if($type == "AX") {
    $pattern = "/^([34|37]{2})([0-9]{13})$/";//American Express
    if (preg_match($pattern,$cc_num)) {
    $verified = true;
    } else {
    $verified = false;
    }


    } elseif($type == "DC") {
    $pattern = "/^([30|36|38]{2})([0-9]{12})$/";//Diner's Club
    if (preg_match($pattern,$cc_num)) {
    $verified = true;
    } else {
    $verified = false;
    }


    } elseif($type == "DS") {
    $pattern = "/^([6011]{4})([0-9]{12})$/";//Discover Card
    if (preg_match($pattern,$cc_num)) {
    $verified = true;
    } else {
    $verified = false;
    }


    } elseif($type == "MC") {
    $pattern = "/^([51|52|53|54|55]{2})([0-9]{14})$/";//Mastercard
    if (preg_match($pattern,$cc_num)) {
    $verified = true;
    } else {
    $verified = false;
    }


    } elseif($type == "VI") {
    $pattern = "/^([4]{1})([0-9]{12,15})$/";//Visa
    if (preg_match($pattern,$cc_num)) {
    $verified = true;
    } else {
    $verified = false;
    }

    }

    if($verified == false) {
    //Do something here in case the validation fails
    echo "Credit card invalid. Please make sure that you entered a valid <em>" . $denum . "</em> credit card ";

    } else { //if it will pass...do something
    echo "Your <em>" . $denum . "</em> credit card is valid";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Looks at all the places you return, and consider whether you'd like to return `true` or `false`. That's about it. If you're confused about this, though, I'd recommend against handling credit card information. It's hard to get this sort of thing right, and you'd probably find it easier and safer to use someone else's credit card processing library.

Comment: You can't put a `return` out of the blue, you should be inside a `function` body. Anyway you should wrap your checks in functions in order to make your code more readable.

Comment: @moonwave99: I'd guess that this is weird code that returns to an `include` call. It's bad form, but it's also totally valid.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, well I found this code in the web, and works, but I need to integrate it in my php form validator and thats why I need the return true and false depending on the validation and the error message :)

Comment: I just added another code so I would like to add the $verified variable to the first code, is possible to add something similar?

Comment: this is not the proper way to validate credit card numbers: http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/creditcard.php

Comment: thanks @Dagon , that seems to be the original file, is a little different, I just need to configure a IF variable like this: if(return == true) { echo'work'; } elseif(return == false) { echo $errortext; }

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable at the top of your function:

```
$invalid = false;
```

Then everywhere in your code where you have `return true;` change it to: `$invalid = true;`.

Then you can just do `return $invalid;` at the end of your function. It will return `true` if there was an error. If there is no error it will return `false`.

Comment: Why assign a variable and keep checking rather than return immediately? Also, `$invalid` feels like a backwards variable name. How about `$valid`?

Comment: @Matchu He doesn't want to return immediately. He wants to continue with the validation so that all the error messages get generated for each error. Also he is returning `true` when there is an error, that's why I named the variable `invalid`. It seems backwards to me as well but for all we know this could be inside a function called `is_invalid` or something.

Comment: thanks for the answer, well seems to have the idea, but didn't work to me

Answer (score 0):

Look at all the `if` statements that look like this:

```
$errornumber = whateverNumber;
$errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
return true;
```

Those are what return `true` when there is an error. Simply change the return statement to `return false;` in those places to make the script return false.

The only `return true;` should be at the end of your function.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, well I just do it, seems to work, but I just need to configure a IF variable like this: if(return == true) { echo'work'; } elseif(return == false) { echo $errortext; }

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help, here is the final code, I just make some changes and works great:

```
  $cards = array (  array ('name' => 'American Express', 
                          'length' => '15', 
                          'prefixes' => '34,37',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'Diners Club Carte Blanche', 
                          'length' => '14', 
                          'prefixes' => '300,301,302,303,304,305',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'Diners Club', 
                          'length' => '14,16',
                          'prefixes' => '36,38,54,55',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'Discover', 
                          'length' => '16', 
                          'prefixes' => '6011,622,64,65',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'Diners Club Enroute', 
                          'length' => '15', 
                          'prefixes' => '2014,2149',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'JCB', 
                          'length' => '16', 
                          'prefixes' => '35',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'Maestro', 
                          'length' => '12,13,14,15,16,18,19', 
                          'prefixes' => '5018,5020,5038,6304,6759,6761,6762,6763',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'MasterCard', 
                          'length' => '16', 
                          'prefixes' => '51,52,53,54,55',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'Solo', 
                          'length' => '16,18,19', 
                          'prefixes' => '6334,6767',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'Switch', 
                          'length' => '16,18,19', 
                          'prefixes' => '4903,4905,4911,4936,564182,633110,6333,6759',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'VISA', 
                          'length' => '16', 
                          'prefixes' => '4',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'VISA Electron', 
                          'length' => '16', 
                          'prefixes' => '417500,4917,4913,4508,4844',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         ),
                   array ('name' => 'LaserCard', 
                          'length' => '16,17,18,19', 
                          'prefixes' => '6304,6706,6771,6709',
                          'checkdigit' => true
                         )
                );

  $ccErrorNo = 0;

  $ccErrors [0] = "Unknown card type";
  $ccErrors [1] = "No card number provided";
  $ccErrors [2] = "Credit card number has invalid format";
  $ccErrors [3] = "Credit card number is invalid";
  $ccErrors [4] = "Credit card number is wrong length";

  // Establish card type
  $cardType = -1;
  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($cards); $i++) {

    // See if it is this card (ignoring the case of the string)
    if (strtolower($cardname) == strtolower($cards[$i]['name'])) {
      $cardType = $i;
      $response = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // If card type not found, report an error
  if ($cardType == -1) {
     $errornumber = 0;     
     $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
     $response = false;
     return false; 
  }

  // Ensure that the user has provided a credit card number
  if (strlen($cardnumber) == 0)  {
     $errornumber = 1;     
     $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
     $response = false;
     return false; 
  }

  // Remove any spaces from the credit card number
  $cardNo = str_replace (' ', '', $cardnumber);  

  // Check that the number is numeric and of the right sort of length.
  if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{13,19}$/",$cardNo))  {
     $errornumber = 2;     
     $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
     $response = false;
     return false; 
  }

  // Now check the modulus 10 check digit - if required
  if ($cards[$cardType]['checkdigit']) {
    $checksum = 0;                                  // running checksum total
    $mychar = "";                                   // next char to process
    $j = 1;                                         // takes value of 1 or 2

    // Process each digit one by one starting at the right
    for ($i = strlen($cardNo) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {

      // Extract the next digit and multiply by 1 or 2 on alternative digits.      
      $calc = $cardNo{$i} * $j;

      // If the result is in two digits add 1 to the checksum total
      if ($calc > 9) {
        $checksum = $checksum + 1;
        $calc = $calc - 10;
      }

      // Add the units element to the checksum total
      $checksum = $checksum + $calc;

      // Switch the value of j
      if ($j ==1) {$j = 2;} else {$j = 1;};
    } 

    // All done - if checksum is divisible by 10, it is a valid modulus 10.
    // If not, report an error.
    if ($checksum % 10 != 0) {
     $errornumber = 3;     
     $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
     $response = false;
     return false; 
    }
  }  

  // The following are the card-specific checks we undertake.

  // Load an array with the valid prefixes for this card
  $prefix = explode(',',$cards[$cardType]['prefixes']);

  // Now see if any of them match what we have in the card number  
  $PrefixValid = false; 
  for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($prefix); $i++) {
    $exp = '/^' . $prefix[$i] . '/';
    if (preg_match($exp,$cardNo)) {
      $PrefixValid = true;
      $response = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // If it isn't a valid prefix there's no point at looking at the length
  if (!$PrefixValid) {
     $errornumber = 3;     
     $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
     $response = false;
     return false; 
  }

  // See if the length is valid for this card
  $LengthValid = false;
  $lengths = explode(',',$cards[$cardType]['length']);
  for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($lengths); $j++) {
    if (strlen($cardNo) == $lengths[$j]) {
      $LengthValid = true;
      $response = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // See if all is OK by seeing if the length was valid. 
  if (!$LengthValid) {
     $errornumber = 4;     
     $errortext = $ccErrors [$errornumber];
     $response = false;
     return false; 
  };   

  // The credit card is in the required format.
  return $response;
```

in the other page:

```
$cardnumber = $_POST['CardNumber']; 
$cardname = $_POST['CardType'];

require('phpcreditcard.php');



  if ($response == true) {
      echo 'works';
  }
  elseif ($response == false) {
    echo $errortext;
  }
```